# how to move a (basket)ball across the screen with delay?

Tags: javascript, animation, wait

I have an image of a ball that I wish to move using JS. I will add more precise code later for .left and .top that will precisely describe the throw of the ball with gravity function. What I have now goes too fast to see.

I have:

HTML

`<img id="bal1" src="Afbeeldingen/bal1.png" alt="Bal" width="100" height="100">`

JS

```
    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      document.getElementById('bal1').style.left=30*x +"px";
      document.getElementById('bal1').style.top=30*x +"px";
    
    }
```

This works, but it goes too fast to see the movement. How would I make this into a visible animation?

thanks!

Comment: Why not use CSS animations and skip the javascript? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can make a game loop using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

```js
const speed = 0.1; // Set the ball speed

const ball = document.getElementById("ball1") // Find the ball
let startTime = Date.now();

function tick() {
  const time = Date.now() - startTime; // miliseconds since game started
  
  // move the ball
  ball.style.left = time * speed + "px";
  ball.style.top = time * speed + "px";
  
  // Stop after 300 pixels traveled
  const traveled = ball.style.left.slice(0, -2); // The ball's position has "px" at the end, so this line of code removes it.
  if (traveled > 300) return; // Return early instead of calling the next frame
  
  // call tick next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

// Start the game
tick();
```

```css
#ball1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img id="ball1" src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_20affc7e-e0d7-4eb6-a6f3-68d13520f8be?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg" alt="Ball" width="100" height="100">
```

### Or, even better, use CSS.

You can use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animations/Using_CSS_animations) to move the ball **without** Javascript.

```css
/* Create the animation */
@keyframes ballAnimation {
  from { /* The ball starts... */
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  to { /* And ends up... */
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px;
  }
}

#ball1 {
  /* Set the ball's position to absolute*/
  position: absolute;
  
  /* Give the animation to the ball */
  animation-name: ballAnimation;
  animation-duration: 3s; // s stands for seconds
}
```

```html
<img id="ball1" src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_20affc7e-e0d7-4eb6-a6f3-68d13520f8be?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg" alt="Ball" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: Wow! I pasted the JS code and that obviously works  Thanks so much! The only thing is I don't quite understand how the "window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)" works exactly, so I'll need to dive into that a bit more. Specifically, I don't understand how this function handles the time between each frame or the frame refresh speed. For instance, what would I change to make the ball go faster or slower?

Comment: `window.requestAnimationFrame` calls the function given on the next frame. `Date.now` is the one calculating the time. `Date.now` returns the number of miliseconds since January 1, 1970 started. For example, you can set `startTime` to `Date.now()` and get the miliseconds since the game started by using `Date.now() - startTime`. In this case, you would change the `speed` variable to change the speed of the ball. (defined at the top of the code to make the ball go faster)

Comment: Thank you, yes I understand what you're saying. What I meant is how can I change the function call frequency. const speed is basically a multiplier for the position of  ball.style.left/top. So by increasing speed, the function call cycle still has the same frequency. How would I change that frequency? I don't see any variable that could control that. Is that built into the requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` calls the function on the next frame. So that means if your moniter's refresh rate is 60hz, the function will be called every 60th of a second. This is useful if you want your game to take full advantage of a user's refresh rate,  which I would recommend, but if you need a set refresh rate you can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval). For example. `setInterval(function() {console.log("one second has passed")}, 1000)` will log to the console every 1000 miliseconds (1 second).

Comment: Excellent, that is the missing piece. Thank you. Meanwhile I completed the project, thanks to your help!